# Image is getting saved as id while using multer

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, multer

I am trying to upload an image using multer but the images gets saved as an Id .

I have tried to set the file name to original name still the name of file doesn't  change

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, './uploads')
    }},{
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.originalname + '-' + Date.now())
  }
})
var upload = multer({ storage: storage })
let PhotoModel = require('../models/photo')

router.post('/',upload.single('image'),(req, res, next) => {





    let msg = new PhotoModel(
        {images: req.file.originalname}


      )
      msg.save()
         .then(doc => {
           console.log(doc)
         })
         .catch(err => {
           console.error(err)
         })

    res.send(msg)


})
```

Comment: How's your PhotoModel defined? you're only passing the filename to your database not your entire file

Comment: Yes I am only passing the filename on to mongodb.I have used filename :function to convert the id to photo name but for some reason it doesn't work as it still gives me the id.I am storing these images in a  server